# Abbreviations like HTH (hope that helps) for Internet and messaging slang

Tags: argot, correspondance, jargon, internet

> The phrase “hope this helps,” abbreviated HTH, is common in Internet
>   and digital messaging slang. This particular phrase is often used in
>   workplace situations as people interact and try to solve problems. https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31483/hope-this-helps-hth

Are abbreviations like HTH and similar ones like those given below

https://www.anglaisfacile.com/free/voc/sms.php

accepted in French Internet and messaging slang? If not, how, for instance, we convey in French the idea of Hope This/That Helps (HTH)?

Comment: FYI & TWIMC, FTS!  (IMHO) ;-)

Comment: Few of these English abbreviations can be used (understood) in French. I learned HTH by reading your message :) (thanks). And no, there's no equivalence for "hope this helps"

Comment: En fait, un français n'espère pas que ça aide : il le sait. ça fait partie de sa suffisance :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are abbreviations like HTH and similar ones

yes, there is a lot of abbreviations in french to use in messaging,

simple ones can be found either in french and in English as @paradise said,

for example, message become msg.

But here is a short list of abbreviations that we can use:

'ne t'inquiète pas': (this one is used when someone says thanks)

> - firstly became : t'inquiète
> - then : tkt (T'inKièTe)

'à plus tard':

> - 'à plus'
> - 'a+'

'Salutations' (i think it's the base of this abbreviation)

> - 'Salut'
> - 'slt'

'merci'

> - 'mrc'

Right now, i can't think about complex abbs. with multiple words. They might be not very common.

here is a link covering this side of the french language, (but keep in mind that it might be outdated since language in generale tend to change)
[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_SMS)

hope this helps ;)

Comment: in police series you can even find 'R.A.S' meaning 'Rien à Signaler'